# Iterate Through Workbook; Copy & Paste Data to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

**Background**

I receive a bunch of excel workbooks (AUTHORIZED EXPENSES) from various BUSINESS UNITS throughout the world. My objective is to create a macro that opens each BUSINESS UNIT'S workbook, copy their expense data, and paste it into a master file for easy comparison.

**PROCESS**

1. Create a tab for each BUSINESS UNIT in the TARGET_WORKBOOK (*this is done outside of the macro*)
2. For each tab in TARGET_WORKBOOK, have some meta data that helps the
   macro in navigating to the BUSINESS UNIT's proper file path
       (SOURCE_WORKBOOK)
3. Open correct SOURCE_WORKBOOK and navigate to "Auth Expense Data
   Entry" tab within the SOURCE_WORKBOOK
4. Copy data from SOURCE_WORKBOOK to TARGET_WORKBOOK, clear clipboard
   cache, close SOURCE_BOOK
5. **ISSUE** - *Move to next tab in SOUCE_WORKBOOK and repeat Step 1*

**CODE**

```
Sub AllUnits()

Dim Current As Worksheet

'For every worksheet in workbook, call AuthExpense function
For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Call AuthExpense(Current)
Next Current

End Sub


Sub AuthExpense(Current As Worksheet)

Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Path As String


'Configure macro for business-specific unit
BusinessUnit = ActiveSheet.Name
BusinessName = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)

'Declare Target & Source workbooks w/ relative paths
Set Target_Workbook = ThisWorkbook
Source_Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Business Unit Monthly Reporting Template_" & BusinessName & ".xlsx"
Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Source_Path)

'Copy Source Workbook to Target Workbook
Source_Workbook.Sheets("Auth Expense Data Entry").Range("A1:H150").Copy

'Paste Special Source data to Target workbook
Target_Workbook.Sheets(BusinessUnit).Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Clear clipboard cache and close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Source_Workbook.Close (False)


End Sub
```

**NOTE**

- I can successfully open, copy, paste, clear clipboard cache, and close a BUSINESS UNIT's workbook.

**ISSUES**

1. My issues occurs in the looping/iteration function ("AllUnits()"). When the macro runs, the Master Excel file copy/pastes the same business unit's data 10 times (on the same worksheet, overwriting itself). I believe my issue occurs when I try to move over to the next tab on the Master File. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your sub `AuthExpense`, change all references to `ActiveSheet` to `Current` and it should work.

Comment: When I change "Active" to "Current", the macro only loops through one iteration. Why would this occur?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AllUnits()` sub has no problems. It should just loop through the sheets in the workbook it is housed in. You must change you sub `AuthExpense` to not reference the `ActiveSheet`. You never activate the sheet in your `AllUnits()` sub, so the next sheet isn't the active one. Use the below.

```
Sub AllUnits()

Dim Current As Worksheet

'For every worksheet in workbook, call AuthExpense function
For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Call AuthExpense(Current)
Next Current

End Sub


Sub AuthExpense(Current As Worksheet)

Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Path As String


'Configure macro for business-specific unit
BusinessUnit = Current.Name
BusinessName = Current.Cells(2, 2)

'Declare Target & Source workbooks w/ relative paths
Set Target_Workbook = ThisWorkbook
Source_Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Business Unit Monthly Reporting Template_" & BusinessName & ".xlsx"
Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Source_Path)

'Copy Source Workbook to Target Workbook
Source_Workbook.Sheets("Auth Expense Data Entry").Range("A1:H150").Copy

'Paste Special Source data to Target workbook
Target_Workbook.Sheets(BusinessUnit).Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Clear clipboard cache and close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Source_Workbook.Close (False)


End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW - `Target_Workbook.Sheets(BusinessUnit)` can be replaced by `Current` (because `BusinessUnit` was set to be the Name of the `Current` worksheet in ThisWorkbook and `Target_Workbook` has been set to `ThisWorkbook`).

Comment: When I change "Active" to "Current", the macro only loops through one iteration. Furethermore, it appears that it's now appending my Windows USERNAME to the file path. Why would this occur?

Comment: How many worksheets are in the workbook this code is housed in? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: 10 source_workbooks, each with 20 tabs. Since I am only copying one tab per source_workbook, the target_workbook therefore has 10 tabs.

Comment: Can you step through the code and check your variables? There is nothing wrong with the code, so I anticipate something isn't named right, etc

Comment: @kidlogic - The macros are located in the workbook (target_workbook) that contains 10 sheets (one for each business unit)?  And each of the 10 sheets has a valid business name in cell B2?

Comment: @YowE3K this is correct.


please disregard my previous comment about the function inserting my USERNAME - this was due to another page that holds meta data concerning the last author of the workbook.

Comment: @kidlogic - I assume you have now deleted that extra worksheet, or changed your code to say something like `If Current.Name <> "whatever bad sheet is called" Then` `Call AuthExpense(Current)` `End If`.  Does it still only go through the loop once?